# How can i parse a part of a string that is in UTF-8 into a string in C++?

Tags: c++, c, json, parsing

I'm reading a string from a JSON file in C++ and when comes a special character in the middle of the string like 'ç' or 'á', it turns the character into '\u00e7' and '\u00e1'.

The word i'm reading it's "Praça" and when i read from the JSON file turns into "Pra\u00e7a".
The special character "ç" it's turning into "\u00e7". I want to know how can i parse back to "Praça".

Comment: How is this causing you a problem?

Comment: That's not UTF8. With that misconception out of the way: what does "turn into" mean? You get the actual 6 characters \, `u`, `0`, another `0`, `e` and `7` or `1`?

Comment: It would help to see the code that "turns the character".

Comment: The word i'm reading it's "Praça" and when i read from the JSON file turns into "Pra\u00e7a". The special character "ç" it's turning into "\u00e7";

Comment: You are wrong (again!). The character does not **turn** into a Unicode-escaped hexadecimal format. It is just *stored* that way, to prevent character encoding miscommunication.

Comment: This App it's for TIZEN native, so i used their parser. When the string has special characters, it turns into something like that '\u00e7'.

Comment: JSON transfers Unicode characters—let's not look at how just yet. What character set and encoding do you want to use in your C++ and in what data structure? Unicode/UTF-8 in `std::string`?

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing it right. When a string is encoded into utf-8, and you read it, you don't want to change anything. The string is already correct in memory.

The problem is with whatever system is displaying the string doesn't handle utf-8, and is displaying it in C/C++/Java source code encoding.

Your best bet is to fix the systems that process and display your strings to handle utf-8. If you can't do that and are restricted to using ascii- then you can map some of the unicode characters back to ascii. But you won't be able to handle most characters ( e.g. all asian characters for example ). You'll basically be going back to a pre-unicode world.

If that is the best you can do then here is your mapping:

```
bool KxnUTF8Code::decode( const char* str )
{
assert( str );
clear();

bool ret = true;

const char* cstr = str;
int len = strlen( str );

while ( *cstr )
{
   char c = cstr[0];
   if ( c >= 0x80 )
   {
     // this is a high bit character - starts a unicode character. Try converting to ascii
     if ( c == 0xc2 )
     {
        // decode a utf character in the 0xC2 range. 
        c = cstr[1];
        if (( c >= 0x80 ) && ( c <= 0xBF ))
        {
           // Only characters from 0x80-0xBF range are valid ascii
           write( &c, 1 );

        } else {

           // not ascii - you're boned.
           c = '?';
           write( &c, 1 );
           ret = false;
        }

        cstr += 2;

     } else if ( c == 0xc3 ) {

        // decode a utf character in the 0xC3 range. 
        c = cstr[1];
        if (( c >= 0x80 ) && ( c <= 0xBF ))
        {
           // Only characters from 0x80-0xBF range are valid
           c += 0x40;
           write( &c, 1 );

        } else {

           // not ascii - screwed again...
           c = '?';
           write( &c, 1 );
           ret = false;
        }

        cstr += 2;

     } else {

        // none of the longer codes are ascii either... 
        int codeLen = 1;

             if (( c >= 194 ) && ( c <= 223 )) codeLen = 2;
        else if (( c >= 224 ) && ( c <= 239 )) codeLen = 3;
        else if (( c >= 240 ) && ( c <= 247 )) codeLen = 4; // not all of these are yet allocated.
        else if (( c >= 248 ) && ( c <= 251 )) codeLen = 5; // none of these are allocated
        else if (( c >= 252 ) && ( c <= 253 )) codeLen = 6; // none of these are allocated

        cstr += codeLen; 

        c = '?';
        write( &c, 1 );
        ret = false;
     }

  } else {

     // unmodified ascii character.
     write( &cstr[0], 1 );
     cstr++;
  }
}

return ret;
}
```